# nodejs loop in asynch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

Im sending user information to user when he signs in.

```
var userstuff00 = findSub(user['id']);
userstuff00.then(function(sub){
    for(var i in sub){
        var userstuff01 = findSub(sub[i.toString()]['id']);
        userstuff01.then(function(sub2){
            for(var i2 in sub2){
                 //here i is the last object in sub but i2 is for the first i
                console.log(sub[i.toString()]);
                console.log(sub2[i2.toString()]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and this is findSub function where usercollection is mongodb table:

```
function findSub(stuffCode){
        var tempMembers = usercollection.find({'stuff ': stuffCode});
        return tempMembers;
}
```

this is user object :

```
user{
    id,
    name,
    stuff,
    subMember[] //list of users where their stuff equals to this users id
}
```

I want to add every `sub2` in that users `subMember` but `i`'s id is not equal to `i2`'s stuff( I cant add `i2` in another `i`'s submember).

how can get submembers for  the first `i` and then find submembers for the second `i`?

my goal is a list of users that has users as submembers and these users(submembers level 1) have submembers(submembers level 2) and so on (up to level 10) :
[Family Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yQem.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical issue when working with asynchronous code: the synchronous code will finish *before* any of the *asynchronous* code. So this loop:

```
for(var i in sub)
```

... will *finish* before any of the `then` callbacks inside it will be executed. So by the time one of those gets executed, the value of *i* is already the length of *sub*.

To be able to use the value of the *i* at the time you called `then` (not its callback), there are different solutions. One of them is to use `let i` instead of `var i` as it will define a different variable on each iteration of the `for` loop. Or you can bind the value of *i* as argument to the `then` callback:

```
    userstuff01.then(function(i, sub2){
    //                        ^^^ added parameter
        for(var i2 in sub2){
             //here i is the last object in sub but i2 is for the first i
            console.log(sub[i.toString()]);
            console.log(sub2[i2.toString()]);
        }
    }.bind(null, i));
 //    ^^^^^^^^^^^ bind the parameter value to the current value of i.
```

Comment: i cant use bind throws this `TypeError: userstuff01.then(...).bind is not a function`  but `let i` worked.

Comment: swap i and sub2 in `function(i, sub2)` and it worked. thanks

Comment: In fact, bind needs the context as first argument, which I also had not included. Updated.